# Approach for Virtual Keyboard IME for android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I wish to implement a virtual keyboard IME for android. But when I go for references with android's provided softkeyboard sample it says

> This code is focused on simplicity over completeness, so it should in
>   no way be considered to be a complete soft keyboard implementation.

So what are other things that I need to take care to implement custom IME.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of keyboard you plan to make. The sample is a full working keyboard - although not very advanced. I used it as a starting point, when I made my own keyboard: [Maxikeys](http://www.maxikeys.com). It worked OK for that - although I think the documentation could be improved a bit - maybe it was just because I had to combine it with a GLSurfaceView.

have fun

Hardy Henneberg